# Tour.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update an existing document in the Tour collection after creating a new review using post middleware. but I get this error:

> Tour.findByIdAndUpdate is not a function.

code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Tour = require('./tourmodule');
review_schema.statics.calcAverageRating = async function(tourId) {
  const stats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { ref_to_tour: tourId }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$ref_to_tour',
        nRating: { $sum: 1 },
        avgRating: { $avg: '$rating' }
      }
    }
  ]);
   console.log(stats);

  await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(tourId, {
    ratingsQuantity: stats[0].nRating,
    ratingsAverage: stats[0].avgRating
  });
};

review_schema.post('save', function() {
  this.constructor.calcAverageRating(this.ref_to_tour);
});
const Review = mongoose.model('Review', review_schema);
module.exports = Review;
```

Comment: What's `Tour`, can you show the code of the `tourmodule`?